# Reorder certain columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, with the following columns, in this order;

```
'2','4','9','A','1','B','C'
```

I want the first 3 columns to be ABC but the rest it doesn't matter.

Output:

```
'A','B','C','3','2','9'... and so on
```

Is this possible?

(there are 100's of columns, so i can't put them all in a list

Comment: is it just `A,B,C` or all string columns should come first?

Comment: just A, B, C, i just used numbers in my example, but all columns are strings in my actual dataframe

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try to reorder like this:

```
first_cols = ['A','B','C']
last_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in first_cols]

df = df[first_cols+last_cols]
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Setup

```
cols = ['2','4','9','A','1','B','C']
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(3), cols)

df

   2  4  9  A  1  B  C
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

#### `sorted` with `key`

```
key = lambda x: (x != 'A', x != 'B', x != 'C')
df[sorted(df, key=key)]

   A  B  C  2  4  9  1
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Better suited for longer length of first column members

```
first_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
key = lambda x: tuple(y != x for y in  first_cols)
df[sorted(df, key=key)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`columns.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
first = ['A', 'B', 'C']

out = df[first+list(df.columns.difference(first, sort=False))]
```

Or, if there is a chance that a name from `first` is not present in `df`:

```
first = ['A', 'B', 'C']

out = df.reindex(columns=first+list(df.columns.difference(first, sort=False)))
```